# Angular: Problemas com TouchEvents

Tags: angular, javascript-eventos, touch

Preciso detectar um `touchstart`, um `touchend` e um `touchmove` para fazer uma seleção de dias conforme o usuário arrasta o dedo na tela. Porem o evento `touchmove` aparentemente não foi feito para esse fim. Conforme o exemplo abaixo, ele vai ficar me retornando apenas o primeiro dia.

> Controller

```
@Component({
     selector: 'app-calendar',
     templateUrl: 'url.html'
})
export class Calendar {
    touchStart() {
        console.log('start');
    }

    touchHover(dia) {
        console.log('hover >> ' + dia);
    }

    touchEnd() {
        console.log('end');
    }
}
```

> HTML

```
<div (touchstart)="touchStart()" (touchend)="touchEnd()">
     <div (touchmove)="touchHover('1')">1</div>
     <div (touchmove)="touchHover('2')">2</div>
     <div (touchmove)="touchHover('3')">3</div>
</div>
```

Eu preciso receber cada elemento após o `touchstart`, conforme o usuário passe sob ele no dispositivo. O `touchmove` é executado porém ele sempre vai me retornar o elemento onde iniciei o touch. Exemplo: Se startei o touch no dia 1, ele vai ficar retornando 1 independente deu estar movendo sob o dia 2.

Alguém já passou por esse problema? Sabem como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Testando no Chrome Dev Tools os eventos de `mouse` parecem funcionar para toque (pendente de teste em dispositivo real).

```
<div (mouseenter)="touchStart()" (mouseleave)="touchEnd()">
  <div (mouseenter)="touchHover('1')">1</div>
  <div (mouseenter)="touchHover('2')">2</div>
  <div (mouseenter)="touchHover('3')">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Patrick, bom dia tudo bem? Os eventos mouse* não funcionam no mobile. Por isso que estou utilizando os eventos touch*